# Properly express two non-decreasing functions do not increase simultaneously

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two non-decreasing right-continuous functions. I have seen in an article where it is written that for all $t\geq 0$
\begin{equation}\label{eqq}
df(t)dg(t)=0.
\end{equation}
I understand the author meant these two functions do not increase together. However, I am not sure if '$df(t)dg(t)$' makes sense. Since they are non-decreasing, then $f$ and $g$ can induce two measures $F((s, t]) = f(t) − f(s) $ and $G((s, t]) = g(t) − g(s)$ and then can define integrals over them (i.e. Lebesgue–Stieltjes integration). But I'm still not sure how to rigoriously express `two functions do not increase simultaneously'.

Comment: Either the article is wrong or you are quoting it wrongly. You can find trivial counter-examples.

Comment: Yes i believe the article is wrong in this  which is why I'm posting this question.

Comment: Just guessing, but perhaps the condition was something like $\int_a^b \frac{df(t)dg(t)}{dt} = 0$ interpreted as a Hellinger integral.   Most likely that would imply that $f'(t)g'(t)=0$ almost everywhere.  But ...just guessing.

Comment: There is also **Section 5.9 Mutually singular functions** in this textbook that uses the integral $\int_a^b \sqrt{dF(x)dG(x)} =0$ to define two functions $F$ and $G$ of bounded variation as being "mutually singular."  Again $F'(x)G'(x)=0$ a.e..  See  http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/toti-screen-June11-2013.pdf  but I rather doubt that was the exact reference you would have found.